# MySQL: Is it faster to read a big data in a single Cell or smaller data in many Cells?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I am passing some values into a MySQL Database table and I was thinking if it was faster to pass the entire javascript array of objects as a string or if I should split them up into cells in terms of speed.

Example:

Javascript array:

```
var a = {'sky':'blue', 'grass':'green', 'sun':'yellow', 'milk':'white', 'rose':'red', 'facebook':'whiteblue'};
```

Example 1:

**Table Rows/Values**

```
id: 1
sky: blue
grass: green
sun: yellow
milk: white
rose: red
facebook: whiteblue
```

Example 2:

**Table Rows/Values**

```
id: 2
data: {'sky':'blue', 'grass':'green', 'sun':'yellow', 'milk':'white', 'rose':'red', 'facebook':'whiteblue'}
```

Because at the end of the day, I would need to retrieve from the database all the data and pass it as a javascript array of objects.

What would it be faster to perform?

Comment: why don't you try and tell us? :) google chrome has some nice performance profilling tools

Comment: `Is it faster to read a big data in a single Cell`

Comment: @povilasp Maybe there would be other issues i am not aware of, of doing such an action

Comment: You also need to consider what queries you might make against this table

Comment: Don't you ever think you'll need to do a query with a condition like `WHERE sky = 'blue'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no question which is faster.
There is a question of sane design.

Either use first approach, or don't bother with database at all.
Mysql is a relational database management system. So, it have to be used to store atomized data, able to make whatever relations, filtering ordering and such. If you don't need any of them, you don't need a relational database.

Also, bother yourself with performance questions only if there is a real problem.
Otherwise you'd just waste your time or make things even worse.

Comment: +1, a well-known saying about premature optimisation also springs to mind.

Comment: Ah I see why you're saying that. Basically If I am going on this approach I will need a non-relational database ?